# converting python file into ui file error

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

I converted the UI file into a python file but when I need to modify the design, I cannot convert the python file to a UI file again

I have typed this command in the cmd:

```
C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyuic5.exe -x test.py -o test.ui
```

and I got this:

[image: error screenshot]

and in the cmd I got this:

```
Access is denied.
```

I am using PyQt5, pyuic5

what is the problem? and Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `pyuic5`?

Comment: try with: `python -m "PyQt5.uic.pyuic" -x test.py -o test.ui`

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried this command and I got `Error: Permission denied: "test.ui"`

Comment: In which folder have you opened the cmd? I think you have placed the cmd in a folder that you do not have permission, so it throws that error, try changing the folder.

Comment: I opened the cmd on the desktop because the file is on the desktop

Comment: I tried now in another folder and I got this error `Error in input file: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1`

Comment: @MohamedAmenthat second error indicates that the .ui file is badly formed, I recommend you recreate the file since surely in one of your attempts you damaged the file. Please use  `@username`

Comment: I don't know how to use @username